# Chunked query vs not - significant time difference

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, explain

I have a PostgreSQL query which has around 5 million rows in the FROM table of the query. If I run the query to save results to table without a WHERE clause it never finishes. However, if add a WHERE clause and restrict to bands of 1m on the base table ID field it finishes quickly, and I can execute across the whole population in minutes.

Are there any generic ideas that might explain why such a big difference in performance when the query isn't chunked?

Thanks

Comment: If you run a query without WHERE clause, postgres will perform a sequential scan reading the entire table. check the postgres logs if any error is reported during the full sequential scan. using the where clause by column that has an index is expect to be fast.

Comment: Compare the execution plans.

Comment: Without the where clause, the *client* is trying to read the entire table in memory at one time, which is probably causing the system to swap to death.

Comment: @jjanes - sorry I've edited my original question to reflect that I am saving results to table rather than client

Answer (score 0):

Compare both queries  explain running:

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM <tabname>;

and

EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM <tabname> WHERE <column name> = <ID value>;